Has anyone proposed a mission to catch an small asteroid?
The idea here is that you launch a platform into perhaps a medium earth orbit. That platform is equipped with a radar system and an interceptor missile.  When the radar detects an asteroid of the right size flying by along a suitable trajectory, it launches the interceptor missile to rendezvous with it. The interceptor missile then maneuvers the asteroid into an LEO orbit allowing it to later be retrieved and brought back to Earth by a commercial launch provider.
Gathering up samples of the stuff that comes close to Earth seems like a good way to study the solar system.
Has anyone heard of a proposal along these lines or can anyone think of a good reason why it would not be practical?

how closely do you want it to hew to your proposal?  There was a notable proposed asteroid mission of many names and objectives during a time period where Orion needed money but Moon or Mars missions weren't palatable.  I haven't heard any ideas about maintaining in-space infrastructure to do the job.

To clarify, by small this is asking about sub 100kg rocks that are common but tough to detect?

Does  TransAstra Corp.'s Mini Bee count?
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61077/40489

@GremlinWranger Yes, I was thinking of golfball-sized asteroids that come within perhaps 100km.

@blobbymcblobby After a brief read, I don't think it does. That mission seems to be about using a simulated asteroid to test mining techniques.

@ErinAnne I think that's a pretty relevant find. It is a different mission architecture but its benefits would probably have been pitched in a very similar way. Thanks!

https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31746/6944 it was anything but fire & forget

The delta-v on your recovery rockets for this mission profile is probably going to be 10km/s or more. Under absolutely perfect conditions, where the asteroid comes in  on a parabolic trajectory in the plane of , prograde, and tangent your satellite's circular orbit, is going to have a relative velocity of about 1.2 km/s at closest approach.

The Arecibo Telescope had a 305 m antenna diameter and a transmitter with up to 2.5 MW power. Launching a radar system of comparable size is impossible.

@Uwe Arecibo could detect asteroids that were millions of kilometers away. I'm thinking of a platform that detects small asteroids that happen to come quite close to it.

In terms of a probe that waits in Low Earth Orbit for a candidate asteroid to come past, then goes out and grabs it there is not currently any missions matching that exact profile.
There are a couple of reasons for that.
LEO is easy(ish) to get to but the nature of escape velocity means that majority of asteroids passing LEO will be traveling at least that fast, even if starting at low relative velocity around the sun.
Further, the nature of inclination changes in LEO mean that even a 30 degree mismatch between probe and asteroid involves 3.5kms DV. This means our probe needs similar performance to missions that fly out to missions anyway.
Actually getting home again further complicates this, since asteroids arriving from outside the local Earth moon system will generally return there, taking our probe with it on a quite possibly year long odyssey before a low energy return is possible. High energy options of course exist but start making the mission look like assembling a massive multi stage stack in orbit. It would of course be possible to intercept asteroid already on trajectory to earth which at least makes return easy but involves a very very narrow capture window, and very little control over where the probe lands on earth.
The second challenge here is finding objects. If our vehicle can handle up to 100kg return payload we are looking for objects under 50cm across. These objects are findable, but the radars to do so look like the SPY-1, large, not light and needing substantial power source, probably requiring a nuclear reactor rather than solar panels or RTG. And still probably only getting detection to 100s of kms, which does not provide much time to plan and execute and intercept.
If you do succeed at catching an incoming asteroid, putting it in a payload bay and then executing a safe re-entry there is then the question of in what way is this better than just letting that asteroid land, and then picking it up? A captured asteroid will not have been heated during re-entry but finding fallen meteorites is much much cheaper.
Sample return is much more valuable when you can pick known interesting samples that tell us new things - eg Mars, comets (ice does not re-enter well) or specific asteroids that are believed to hold clues to solar system formation. The wait in LEO option gives high odds of a fairly 'boring' sample like those already found on earth. And if it is unusual, a sample size of one does not tell us much!
These combine to explain why all planned and executed asteroid sample missions to date have been to a body and home, rather than waiting for samples to come to us.
Unless you count those missions that search paint or other surfaces of returned equipment for asteroid dust, which is technically 'catching an asteroid'...

The main problem of radar is the necessary power. To increase the maximum distance from 100 km to 1000 km you need 10,000 times the power.

You made some pretty good points. Thanks!
